# How to customize a double integral symbol?

Tags: symbols

I use Mathematica as a notebook,but there is no double integral symbol,there is also no triple integral symbol and so on
If there is any way to customize a symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access such symbols via their unicode. eg enter :222c will give you the double integral symbol. Use MakeBoxes and MakeExpression if you want to modify the typesetting system to make the symbol meaningful.

Comment: it  works ，but the font can not be Times New Roman. And it can’t adjust font size according to the text behind